# How to Dynamically generate for loop based on columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to generate a for loop dynamically based on the number of columns in a dataframe.

For e.g if my columns in dataframe is 5, then I generate the for loop and assign variables accordingly.
if

```
df_cols = ['USER_ID', 'BLID', 'PACKAGE_NAME', 'PACKAGE_PRICE', 'ENDED_DATE']
```

and brics is my dataframe
Then

```
for index, row in brics.iterrows():
  analytics.track(row['USER_ID'], 'Cancelled Subscription', {
    df_cols[1]: row['BLID']
    df_cols[2]: row['PACKAGE_NAME'],
    df_cols[3]: row['PACKAGE_PRICE'],
    df_cols[4]: row['ENDED_DATE'],

      })
```

The df_cols and the row[value] should be generated based on the number of columns in dataframe.
For e.g, if there are only 2 columns in data frame the below is how the code should look like.
if

```
df_cols = ['USER_ID', 'BLID']
```

Then

```
for index, row in brics.iterrows():
      analytics.track(row['USER_ID'], 'Cancelled Subscription', {
        df_cols[1]: row['BLID']
          })
```

I searched SO for this solution but couldnt find the one related to dataframe's (Though R is available). Any pointers will be helpful.THank you.

Comment: do you want to get the first colmun to track and the rest set in a dict? Why don't you use df.columns.values and split the list taking the first value and generating a enumerated list with the rest then create your object

Comment: You can use `cols = df.columns` to create a list of columns in your DataFrame.  Then, you can pass your `index` variable from your loop into `cols[index]` to associate the index to the column name.  (Is this on the track of what you're after?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df_cols = ['USER_ID', 'BLID', 'PACKAGE_NAME', 'PACKAGE_PRICE', 'ENDED_DATE']
for index, row in brics.iterrows():
      analytics.track(row['USER_ID'], 'Cancelled Subscription', {
        df_cols[i+1]: row[df_cols[i]] for i in range(len(df_cols)-1)
          })
```